# Split date range to hours based on Shift Schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a split breakdown of hours worked based on a shift date.
Technically we'll be using 2 dates, the start and end date (datetimes) to determine the per hour an employee worked.
Attached is the sample result that I need to display.

The duration of the shift is not fixed, some has 8hrs less, some has 8hrs more, so the number of records per shift date per employee is not fixed to a number of rows.

```
create table EmployeePunch 
(
    EmployeeId int, 
    TimeStartRaw datetime, 
    TimeEndRaw datetime, 
    ActualStartTime Time, 
    ActualEndTime Time
);
    
insert into EmployeePunch 
(
    EmployeeId, 
    TimeStartRaw, 
    TimeEndRaw, 
    ActualStartTime, 
    ActualEndTime
) values (
    11111,
    '2023-09-10 07:00:07.000',
    '2023-09-10 15:55:45.000',
    '07:00:07.0000000',
    '15:55:45.0000000'
);
```

| EmployeeId | TimeStartRaw | TimeEndRaw | ActualStartTime | ActualEndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 07:00:07.0000000 | 15:55:45.0000000 |

With the sample above, I need to show the following:

| EmployeeId | TimeStartRaw | TimeEndRaw | HourOfDay | MinutesWorked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 7AM | 60 |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 8AM | 60 |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 9AM | 60 |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 10AM | 60 |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 11AM | 60 |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 12PM | 60 |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 13PM | 60 |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 14PM | 60 |
| 1111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 15PM | 55 |

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Please avoid adding your data and results as images. Instead, read the instructions on the [sql-server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, made changes. THanks for letting me know.

Comment: This would so a very easy solution if you do this in your software in stead of in sql, is that possible for you ?

Comment: @GuidoG Cant. I need to generate the raw SQL script unfortunately. 
The SQL script is needed to generate the front end report and not vice versa, sadly. Our software is not yet capable of doing such complicated result using its built in builder.

Comment: Minutes worked always an integer? Rounded?

Comment: @Xedni, integer. Basically a datediff of the next hour. So, for example, the last record, end time is 15:55, starts from 15:00 to 15:55= 55mins. 
If the TimeRaw is 7:05, the HoursWorked will be 55mins towards the next hour which is 8:00. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the range to multiple rows, each represents an hour (or a part of an hour), you can join your table with a numbers table. If you don't already have a numbers table, you can use a common table expression instead.
There are plenty of ways to do that, specifically since we're talking about only 24 rows, I would simply use a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SELECT H
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
  (13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24))V(H)
```

Join that to your `EmployeePunch` table will give you the number or rows you want:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT H
  FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
  (13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24))V(H)
)
SELECT EmployeeId
  , TimeStartRaw
  , TimeEndRaw
  , H
FROM EmployeePunch
INNER JOIN cte
    ON DATEPART(HOUR, ActualStartTime) <= H
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, ActualEndTime) >= H
```

This will give you the following table:

| EmployeeId | TimeStartRaw | TimeEndRaw | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 7 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 8 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 9 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 10 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 11 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 12 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 13 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 14 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 15 |

Now there are a couple more tricks to do to get the time of day and calculate the number of minutes per row: Using `cross apply` with `TimeFromParts` to convert `H` to time of day, and using `dateDiff`, `Lead` and `IsNull` to get the minutes per row:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT H
  FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
  (13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24))V(H)
)
SELECT EmployeeId
  , TimeStartRaw
  , TimeEndRaw
  , HourOfDay
  , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, HourOfDay, ISNULL(LEAD(HourOfDay) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId, CAST(TimeStartRaw As Date) ORDER BY H), TimeEndRaw)) As MinutesWorked
FROM EmployeePunch
INNER JOIN cte
    ON DATEPART(HOUR, ActualStartTime) <= H
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, ActualEndTime) >= H
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(H,0,0,0,0) As HourOfDay) As T
```

| EmployeeId | TimeStartRaw | TimeEndRaw | HourOfDay | MinutesWorked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 07:00:00 | 60 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 08:00:00 | 60 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 09:00:00 | 60 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 10:00:00 | 60 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 11:00:00 | 60 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 12:00:00 | 60 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 13:00:00 | 60 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 14:00:00 | 60 |
| 11111 | 2023-09-10 07:00:07.000 | 2023-09-10 15:55:45.000 | 15:00:00 | 55 |

Note the `PARTITION BY` part of the `LEAD` - I'm assuming your table contains more than one shift for more than one employee.

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/BU2FogoB)

Comment: Thank you! It works! I'll play around with this. But you nailed it. Thank you so much Zohar

Comment: Glad to help :-)